# Question regarding the security of forms in ASP.Net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, forms, webforms

If you were to code a form where let's say you'd input two strings and hit a button to send it into the code.. Would there be a way for the viewer to go into that ASP.Net code and find out what happens to the strings on the click of the button, or is that out of bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. ASP.Net code is `server-side`. All the code is executed on server and only `HTML` is returned to browser. One can not view what is happening inside the server code.